# Issues with this USB ESD protection circuit?

Tags: usb, esd, tvs

I've used this ESD circuit on four boards for hobby projects.  I have had no issues on two boards.  On two others, the TVS diode for VBUS conducted when the board was plugged into a USB port, causing an overcurrent condition and destroying the ESD suppressor (the host is grounding the USB shield). The two working boards have probably just not seen a transient on connection.

Is there a better design for this?  Should there be a resistor between the suppressor and shield ground?  I have not seen this in the reference designs I see published by companies that make TVS diodes and worry this could slow transient response or prevent conduction.

The ESD suppressor in the circuit is a TI ESDS314DBVR, which is four TVS diodes in one package tied to a common ground. Digikey link https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/ESDS314DBVR/296-ESDS314DBVRCT-ND/9745477.

The PTC is a LittleFuse rated for the power requirements of the board.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Who designed the circuit and to what surge or ESD requirement (EN61000 for instance) was it designed to?

Comment: I think the part is an ESD**S**314DBVR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the datasheet:

[image]

Breakdown voltage, IO to GND is the critical parameter. Some parts may conduct at 4.5V, shorting the 5V VBUS to ground and other may not.  This is not a suitable part for VBUS ESD protection.

Comment: That's a good find +1

Comment: Oh, that is a good find.  I missed that in the data sheet.  Thank you.